# What UML relation to use for class A and class C, where class C is a member of Class B and Class A depends on Class B

Tags: oop, uml

Here is a code example.

```
class C;

/* B is a container of class C */
class B
{
public:
    size_t size() const;

    C const& operator[](size_t index) const {
        return elements[index];
    }

    std::vector <C> elements;
}


class D
{
public:
    D(C const& c);
}

/* A is a container of class D */
class A
{
public:
    A(B const& b) {

        // TO construct Class D instance, A needs to pass reference to class C 
        // to class D's constructor.
        for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
            elements.emplace_back(b[i]);
        }
    }
    std::vector <D> elements;
}
```

Here,

1. A COMPOSITION D
2. B COMPOSITION C
3. A DEPENDENCY B
4. D DEPENDENCY C

Which UML relation to use between A and C ?

It is unidirectional Association from A to C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you  are saying (not so sure about your code since my Cxx knowledge is limited):

[image]

As you can clearly see, A depends on C as well since it's a member of B. But you don't need to express that with a dependency since it's obvious.

*Note*: According to the comment of [@Ister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6340948/ister) `A` does not directly depend on `C` since it does not use it. The UML diagram shows that. The dependency is only indirect since (likely) `B` needs `C` to work propertly. Which is why `C` was put inside `B` first hand. But drawing a dependency from `A` to `C` would be wrong here.

Comment: Not really. As it clearly shows A doesn't need to know anything about C nor has to know how B is internally implemented. As a result, there is literally no (direct) relationship between A and C unless it is required for some other reason. Making it a dependency would be against encapsulation and hermetisation principles. From the traceability perspective if there is any change in C or A this change will propagate through B. If for example the interfaces to A aren't changed (as assessed during change impact on B assessment) there is no need to propagate change tracing to A or further.